# Reward in an M/M/$\infty$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

I am looking for help in solving the following problem. Although it looks like a homework problem it's not, it's just a practice in preparation for my exam:

We consider an $M/M/\infty$ where the arrival rate is $\lambda$ and service rate is $\mu$. In addition suppose each customer receives a reward upon departing the queue. Suppose the rewards are iid Exponential($\gamma$). Find the expected value and variance of the total reward paid by time 25.

Comment: If you condition on the number $D$ of departures then the total reward is $R_1 + R_2 + ... + R_D$. For the distribution of $D$, I assume the system is initially empty.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure I understand how to get the distribution of D in this case.

Comment: If you condition on there being $A$ arrivals during $[0, 25]$, then each of the $A$ arrivals is independently and uniformly distributed over $[0,25]$ and $D = \sum_{i=1}^A D_i$.